# underlying topological space of scheme

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

**Definition.**

1. A topological space $X$ is schematizable if there is a scheme whose underlying topological space is $X$. (If you know standard word for this definition, please let me know)
2. A topological space $X$ is spectral if there is a ring $R$ such that $X = \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}R$. It is known that this condition can be described topology theoretically.

**Question.**

Is there a topological space that is not schematizable but has an open covering that consists of spectral spaces ?

Comment: What does "topological glueing" mean exactly?

Comment: A topological space $X$ is  topological glueing of spectral spaces if it has an open covering that consists of spectral spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Every locally spectral space is "schematizable". This is Theorem 9 in Hochster's paper *[Prime Ideal Structure in Commutative Rings](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X.pdf)*, which is also the original source of the theorem (Theorem 6) that every spectral space is "affine schematizable".

Note that the terminology in Hochster's paper agrees with the original edition of EGA, where the word "prescheme" was used for what we call a "scheme" in modern terminology, while the word "scheme" was reserved for what we call a "separated scheme".